# Sign In With Apple + Firebase producing "FIRAuthErrorCodeMissingOrInvalidNonce"

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create an iOS app in which a user logs in using the new "Sign in With Apple Id" Button. I implemented this by:

1. Having the user sign in once and storing their `email`, `identityToken`, and `nonce` in the Keychain as well as in Firebase. (This works - I have verified that the correct data is stored both in the Keychain and in Firebase)
2. Once the user leaves the app and re-opens it, I attempt to pull their existing credentials from the Keychain (I have verified that the correct data is pulled from the Keychain)
3. Once I have the existing credentials from the Keychain, I send them off to Firebase to check if the user already exists, and I keep getting back the `FIRAuthErrorCodeMissingOrInvalidNonce` / `17094` error, despite the fact that I printed out the nonces before and after being stored in the Keychain and they are identical!!

Any ideas on why this might be happening? I am sure that I am *NOT* using the `sha256` or `Data` verison of the nonce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: For future readers - as of Swift 5.5, it appears that Firebase expects "Sign In With Apple" users to use `Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)` only the *FIRST* time  the user signs in. Once the user has been registered, you are then supposed to use `Auth.auth().currentUser?.reauthenticate(with: credential)`!

<strike>Note that this is a bit confusing, since users that sign in the "traditional" way (i.e username + password) can use `Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)` for both sign-in *AND* reauthentication.</strike>

`Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)` genuinely creates a new user each time - use [`signIn`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth) for individual log-in's